# simplify: $\sqrt{75} +4 \sqrt[3]{54} - 6\sqrt{125} - \sqrt[4]{98}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> simplify: $$\sqrt{75} +4 \sqrt[3]{54} - 6\sqrt{125} - \sqrt[4]{98}$$

MyTry :

$$\sqrt{75}=\sqrt{5^2\cdot3}=5\sqrt{3}\\ \sqrt[3]{54}=\sqrt[3]{3^3\cdot2}=3\sqrt[3]{2}\\\ \sqrt{125}=\sqrt{5^3}=5\sqrt{5}\\\sqrt[4]{98}=\sqrt[4]{7^2\cdot2}= \sqrt{7}\cdot \sqrt[4]{2}$$

Thus :

$$\begin{align}\\&=\sqrt{75} +4 \sqrt[3]{54} - 6\sqrt{125} - \sqrt[4]{98}\\&=5\sqrt{3}+12\sqrt[3]{2}-30\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{7}\cdot \sqrt[4]{2}\end{align}$$

now what ?

Comment: Assuming you copied down the problem correctly, that's as simplified as it can get.

Comment: Cube roots and fourth roots of $2$ don't really talk to one another, and neither does any kinds of roots of distinct primes. Thus there is nothing more that can really be done.